# How to migrate Zip dependencies with overlay from Maven to Gradle?

Tags: maven, gradle, dependencies, overlay

I've been trying all day to migrate http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html#Zip_dependencies_with_overlays to Gradle 2.13, but nothing worked. I've tried several solutions mentioned here - http://amanick.blogspot.ro/2015/05/gradle-war-overlay.html

Can anyone give me some hints :D?

Comment: you'll have to give more details about what issues exactly you're facing.

Comment: I'm trying to migrate a project from using maven to using gradle. In my pom.xml file, in <build> section I have something very similar to the link I previously gave. Specifically, it is about http://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/doc/gug/writing-you-own-guacamole-app.html, the section about "describing the configuration of the Maven war plugin, listing guacamole-common-js as an overlay". I tried some solutions and the main issue is that the terminal is not shown. With Maven it works perfectly.